# How to make text stay in one column

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a song analysis. I have a div with 2 columns: one for lyrics, the other for analysis. The problem is that the lyrics are too long (I guess?) and continue to the analysis column.

I just made a div with 2 columns, and expected it to correctly contain my text.

```
#analysis {
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 25px;
    column-rule: 3px solid skyblue;
}
```

So, how do I keep my texts (lyrics, analysis) in their appropriate columns?

Comment: Can you add a [mcve] that includes the HTML, so we can have a better idea of your structure? Rigth now is very hard to understand your goal and what is the current problem you have

Comment: `column-wrap` afaik cannot be controlled except by managing the content accordingly.

Comment: I'd guess using the CSS `white-space` would work, but without the HTML code to see what else could be going on, this is just a WAG. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS columns are not what you want to use for your use case. Instead, give either flex-box or CSS grid a shot:

### flex box

```css
.song-analysis {
  display: flex;
  width: 100;
}

.song-analysis div {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.lyrics {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.analysis {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="song-analysis">

  <div class="lyrics">
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi reiciendis obcaecati nesciunt provident ipsum tenetur dolorem deleniti voluptatibus, odio ipsam blanditiis. Velit corporis vero officia itaque alias, voluptatibus quod ad! Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi reiciendis obcaecati nesciunt provident ipsum tenetur dolorem deleniti voluptatibus, odio ipsam blanditiis. Velit corporis vero officia itaque alias, voluptatibus quod ad! 
  </div>
  <div class="analysis">
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi reiciendis obcaecati nesciunt provident ipsum tenetur dolorem deleniti voluptatibus, odio ipsam blanditiis. Velit corporis vero officia itaque alias, voluptatibus quod ad!
  </div>

</div>
```

### CSS grid

```css
.song-analysis {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.song-analysis div {
  padding: 10px;
}

.lyrics {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.analysis {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="song-analysis">

  <div class="lyrics">
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi reiciendis obcaecati nesciunt provident ipsum tenetur dolorem deleniti voluptatibus, odio ipsam blanditiis. Velit corporis vero officia itaque alias, voluptatibus quod ad! Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi reiciendis obcaecati nesciunt provident ipsum tenetur dolorem deleniti voluptatibus, odio ipsam blanditiis. Velit corporis vero officia itaque alias, voluptatibus quod ad! 
  </div>
  <div class="analysis">
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi reiciendis obcaecati nesciunt provident ipsum tenetur dolorem deleniti voluptatibus, odio ipsam blanditiis. Velit corporis vero officia itaque alias, voluptatibus quod ad!
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you just briefly explain why the columns are not the way to go? Is it simply because cutting off the text is in their nature?

Comment: Think of CSS columns as what you are used to finding in newspapers, where a single article is spread over several columns for better readability. CSS columns are not meanto to give you exact control over where the columns wrap.